# Are questions about improving performance on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope, code-review-se

My understanding is that they are, because poor performance is [a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). However, they also seem on topic on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about), as they satisfy the conditions set in their [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) *[[archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120528053906/https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)]*:

> 1. Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the  question, not a link to it)
> 2. Did I write that code?
> 3. Is it actual code
>    from a project rather then pseudo-code or example code?
> 4. To the best
>    of your knowledge, does the code work?
> 5. Do you want feedback about
>    any or all facets of the code?

The question was brought up in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071772/brute-force-python-over-http#comment14491622_11071772) (edit: the question was removed by the author, possibly because of the comment saying it's off-topic). Is the commenter right?

Should such questions be migrated?

Comment: 10k SO users can still see your question; for everyone else, the same question has now also been posted on CR: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12659/brute-force-http-with-python

Comment: Is it possible to migrate this to Meta SO? It seems like it's still relevant, just on the wrong site. For example it's linked from [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so)

Comment: I posted [a question about migrating this to MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398008/should-this-question-be-migrated-to-mso-are-questions-about-improving-performa), but from what I've found so far, it looks like it makes more sense to leave it. **edit**: NVM, it's way too old to migrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I am the author of the comment in question:*

> I think this is off-topic for StackOverflow, see the faq. Code review questions are better posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

The question did not state a specific problem for us to answer on Stack Overflow; rather, the OP was looking for feedback to improve their code. In that way the question was a better fit for CR than it was for SO.

Had the OP included specific profiling information and a more detailed outline of where the problem with the code lay, it could perhaps be fit for SO too.

Note however that the SO community is (far, *far*) larger than just me, so my 'off-topic' vote is just one opinion. If others agreed and followed up with votes, the question would have been migrated by a moderator had he or she left it on SO.

Comment: The question wasn't mine. You make a good point, but perhaps you could ask for profiling information in a comment to the question.

Comment: Are plain "how can I make this faster" questions really welcome on Code Review though? I'm not familiar with the site, so I really don't know.

Comment: @Pekka: The [CR FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) includes "feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas... [...] * Performance".

Comment: I find it strange that a question that is on topic for CR can be changed into an on-topic SO question just by expanding it with relevant info. It sounds like CR is a place for bad questions about performance, and SO is a place for good ones.

Comment: @Lev yeah, that's why I was unsure, too. But if the folks over at CR are okay with that... *shrug*