# Should this question be migrated to MSO? "Are questions about improving performance on topic on Stack Overflow?"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, mso-mse-split

- [Are questions about improving performance on topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136451/are-questions-about-improving-performance-on-topic-on-stack-overflow)

This question is specific to Stack Overflow and still relevant, since it's been linked from MSO here: [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so), so should it be migrated to MSO?

I looked at [When MSE splits from MSO, what content will be quickly migrated back to MSO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215677/when-mse-splits-from-mso-what-content-will-be-quickly-migrated-back-to-mso) (via [Stack Overflow is getting a Meta of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-meta-of-its-own)), where there were these criteria:

> - Recent (in the past three months)
> - Unresolved (there's obviously a discussion still happening)
> - Very Stack Overflow specific (retag, tag burnination, cleanup, etc)

> A major requirement is to make sure that people keep as much of their rep on MSE as possible, so we're not inclined to pull questions about Stack Overflow that also relate to the network as whole.

This question isn't related to *the network as a whole* seeing as it's closed for being SO-specific.

As for *recent* and *unresolved*, it seems like those were exclusively for the *quick* migration. Content that's still relevant to SO and **only** SO belongs on MSO, right?

Comment: The answer by Catija on the dupe pretty much says what the answers here are saying, and in better and official way.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda She wasn't yet a staff member at the time she wrote that (she was hired in mid-2018) so the statement is not official.

Comment: @Sonic oh, oops. Still, it appears official and with more details.

Answer (score 6):

The question is [far too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

> Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated; this rule also applies to moderators

So regardless of whether you or anyone else thinks it should be migrated, it's not possible.

While staff can migrate after 60 days they would need an extremely compelling reason to do that. So far they only intervened in any significant way once, when Stack Overflow's Meta was being created - various questions from here were migrated at that point to seed the new site.

Comment: Staff can bypass the 60-day limit. It was done back in 2014 when the meta split happened, and is still done in rare cases today.

Comment: @Sonic I considered that too, but it doesn't seem like this case is exceptional enough to warrant that. See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398009/343832), and as Catija said in the dupe, staff aren't likely to go for it.

Comment: I just realized this isn't technically applicable since the only people who can migrate questions on MSE are staff, and staff can bypass the limit. Although, I assume it's applicable in spirit, i.e. staff are less willing to migrate after 60 days even though they can.

Answer (score 2):

No, based on [Stack Overflow meta migration - historical questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230189/stack-overflow-meta-migration-historical-questions), questions that were **resolved** shouldn't be migrated, and this one does have an accepted answer. A new question can be posted on MSO if needed, but otherwise, the question is a bit of a historical artifact.

Effectively, the answers on [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so) reflect the advice in [Martijn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136451/are-questions-about-improving-performance-on-topic-on-stack-overflow/136452#136452):

- *"state a specific problem"*
- Try profiling (or other measurement)
- Think about the problem

  - *"a more detailed outline of where the problem with the code lay"* vs, say, *"considerations around the provided code with regards to the desired goal"* from [Ian's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so/412901#412901)

And various comments and answers discuss considerations about pointing users towards Code Review.

Comment: P.S. This is the best answer I can figure. I'm not sure it's totally correct so I'm open to other answers and I'm not sure it's totally consistent, so edits are appreciated.